# Два сайта с разными доменными именами на одном сервере

Tags: ubuntu, apache, flask

Всем доброго времени суток! Решил открыть небольшой хостинг для сайтов.
Панель управления сделана на асинхронном Flask'е (Quart'е), а сами сайты (поддомены) стоят на Apache.

Операционная система: Ubuntu 18.04

Вопрос: Как "разделить" эти сайты на два различных доменных имени? То есть, панель управления, например, стоит на `example.com`, а сами сайты – на `examplewebsite.com`?
Буду искренне благодарен за ответ.

Comment: В терминологии apache это называется "виртуальные хосты". https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru

Comment: Почитайте про технологию `SNI` (server Name Identification) она позволяет на одном IP держать какое угодно кол-во сайтов с разными доменными именами.